# Image View moving to left side in constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

I created a layout with ImageView constrained at four edges of the screen
[image: Layout Image]
But when i run the app the ImageView is going towards left
[image: Screenshot of activity]

I am unable to figure out the problem

I am providing the xml layout file too. I want to set the Image View at the center of the screen. I am only provindingthe Image View part of the layout.

XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/semiTransparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_of_the_song"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you want design imageview top left of the screen?

Comment: Please share the XML layout.

Comment: I provided the XML layout

Comment: Can you remove this line and see if it works?     app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the constraints can't be fulfilled, you are setting a width and height of the imageview while also attempting to constraint it horizontally.

Change this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_of_the_song"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />
```

to this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_of_the_song"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />
```

Comment: What does adjustViewBounds do?

Comment: Adjusts the size to keep the aspect ratio. You can also use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` depending on your needs.

Comment: I am unable to understand why width and height are affecting constriaints